# Joomla 2.5 add plugin to a component

Tags: module, joomla2.5

I have working on a Component but i reached the point witch i understood that, to make it more efficient i should add a plugin to it for override core , but my questions are :

how to just simply add it to previous component witch i have been created without make user to install two pieces ,if it possible?

Does Joomla 2.5 Understand that i put a plugin in my component or How could i make it to understand that somebody put plugin in a component ?

Any Help would be appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you still need to build the plugin standalone from the component.

You might get more advice if you can be more precise on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can package a component and a plugin together as a 'package' in a xml file. See [this](http://docs.joomla.org/Package) Joomla Docs page for more information. Stuff like Akeeba subs, jDump and many other well known Joomla components use this method!